# MySQL UTC_TIMESTAMP() ignoring current @@time_zone setting

Tags: mysql

I have two Linux/MySQL servers located in the UK, current system timezone on both reports BST (GMT+1) and yet I have found a discrepency in MySQL's output.

The following query:

```
SELECT version(), @@time_zone, @@system_time_zone, NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP()
```

returns:

```
Server A: 5.0.27-community-nt | SYSTEM | GMT | 2010-10-12 12:17:01 | 2010-10-12 11:17:01
Server B: 5.0.45-log | SYSTEM | GMT Daylight Time | 2010-10-12 12:17:51 | 2010-10-12 11:17:51
```

So, server A reports it is set to GMT. The server process was started on 1st March when GMT was in effect, so I expected this. However, the UTC_TIMESTAMP() has correctly (but unexpectedly) reported UTC being 1 hour before localtime.

On server B, the MySQL process was started during the summer, so it correctly reports GMT Daylight Time, and again correctly reports UTC an hour earlier.

My question is, how did server A get the "right" answer? And, will it still be right on October 31st when the localtime reverts to GMT+0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what happens is that when you start the MySQL server, it populates the `@@system_time_zone` variable, but even when it changes (eg. due to DST), it's not reflected in the variable. However, although the `@@system_time_zone` says "GMT", when the MySQL server evaluates the current date, and `@@time_zone` is system, it asks the system for the date and the DST affects that, no matter what `system_time_zone` variable says. So basically the only "issue" here is that `system_timezone` variable does not change automatically, even if the system's timezone changes.

Comment: Thanks for this. Makes me wonder how useful the @@system_time_zone variable actually is, but the following gives me enough information: SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP())